# Paralax banner image scroll from top to bottom

Tags: html, css, parallax

I have a parallax banner which scroll an image. I want the image scroll from top to bottom. Now first you see the bottom of the image and in the end to top.

here is the link: [Example](https://static.a1.ro/advertising/parallax_new_chefi.html)

And here is the code

```css
#dag_box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  
}

#dag_box_int {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    clip: rect(auto,auto,auto,auto);
}
#dag_box_int_img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<a href=""><div id="dag_box">
    <div id="dag_box_int">
        <div id="dag_box_int_img">
            <img id="sas_img_18410319" src="https://static.a1.ro/advertising/i.jpg" alt="" style="top: -13px; bottom: 0px;" >
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
</a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Thank you

Comment: with only css it is not possible you need to apply js for it

Comment: thanks for you answer